# UIO device no longer opens when an interrupt is added

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, zynq-ultrascale+

Linux version: v4.19
Platform: Xilinx Ultrascale+ Zynq

In the Xilinx programmable logic I've created a memory mapped device. I'm using `uio_pdrv_genirq` as my device driver. The device shows up as `uio0` and I'm able to read and write to it without any issues.

Up until now I have not had an interrupt associated with this device. As my design matures, I'm wanting to add an interrupt to the device. So I've created the appropriate logic, connected the interrupt to the CPU, and updated the device tree configuration to tell Linux about the interrupt's existence. I've checked thoroughly and I'm quite certain that I am specifying the correct interrupt ID in the device tree.

However as soon as I specify the interrupt, I start having problems. My user space program hangs when I try to open the device. I've verified with `printf()`:s that I'm no longer exiting this function.

```c
fid = open("/dev/uio0", O_RDWR | O_SYNC);
```

Clearly this has something to do with the interrupt. Perhaps there is some additional device tree configuration of the interrupt controller that I'm missing? Or something I have to do in user space before opening the device?

Here is the device tree configuration for my device and the interrupt controller:

```dts
my_device@a0040000 {
    compatible = "generic-uio";
    reg = <0x0 0xa0040000 0x0 0x40000>;
    interrupt-parent = <&gic>;
    interrupts = <0 89 4>;
};

gic: interrupt-controller@f9010000 {
    compatible = "arm,gic-400", "arm,cortex-a15-gic";
    #interrupt-cells = <3>;
    reg = <0x0 0xf9010000 0x10000>,
          <0x0 0xf9020000 0x20000>,
          <0x0 0xf9040000 0x20000>,
          <0x0 0xf9060000 0x20000>;
    interrupt-controller;
    interrupt-parent = <&gic>;
    interrupts = <1 9 0xf04>;
};
```

Comment: You forgot to share the necessary pieces of the driver code.

Comment: The driver is uio_pdrv_genirq that comes with the kernel.  I haven't touched the driver code in the least.

Comment: With my limited understanding of driver code, I think the driver function called is uio_pdrv_genirq_open() when I open() the device. So presumably it's blocking here.

Comment: Nope, that function is no-op according to https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.19.171/source/drivers/uio/uio_pdrv_genirq.c#L232.

Comment: Then presumably things are blocking in uio_open(). Something that does not block when an interrupt is not assigned. I can't say that I see anything obvious in there.